# Uploading apk in Google Play Console throws error, which I do not understand

Tags: android, google-play, apk, publish

I get the following Message when uploading a new version to Google Play Console.

This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):

```
It is forbidden that a device upgrading from API levels in range 12-23 to API levels in range 24+ should downgrade from version 16 to version 15, which would occur when
Screen layouts containing any of [normal, large, xlarge] and
Features containing all of [android.hardware.FAKETOUCH].

Some devices are eligible to run multiple APKs. In such a scenario, the device will receive the APK with the higher version code.
```

OLD VERSION 15 . My configuration in AndroidManifest (Eclipse) for Version 15 was:

- minSdkVersion="12"
- targetSdkVersion="22"
- maxSdkVersion="23"
- android.permission.VIBRATE
- com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE
- android.permission.INTERNET
- android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
- android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- Compile Version API19 (from build in eclipse)

I have migrated from Eclipse to AndroidStudio
and my new configuration for version 16 is now:

NEW VERSION 16 in AndroidStudio:

- compileSdkVersion 25
- minSdkVersion 12
- targetSdkVersion 22
- maxSdkVersion 23
- android.permission.VIBRATE
- com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE
- android.permission.INTERNET
- android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
- android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Can you check the version code in build.gradle(Module:app)?

Comment: its 16. Did you mean this ?

Comment: I solved it. I had just to remove the maxSdkVersion and then it worked. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your last released codebase targetSdkVersion and compare with current codebase targetSdkVersion version and keep it both same.

It's happen when your last released apk is not updated by anyone and you trying to change your targetSdkVersion +.

Comment: I am not sure , if I understood correct. In my question I mentoined the 2 versions. Both have Target 22. I f I check the lasted uploaded apk, its target SDK is also 22. Do you think I still need to change something ?